# Why does root returned from os.walk() contain / as directory separator but os.sep (or os.path.sep) return \ on Win10?

Tags: python, python-3.x, os.walk, os.path, path-separator

Why does the root element returned from **os.walk()** show / as the directory separator but **os.sep** (or **os.path.sep**) shows \ on Win10?

I'm just trying to create the complete path for a set of files in a folder as follows:

```
import os

base_folder = "c:/data/MA Maps"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(base_folder):
    for f in files:
        if f.endswith(".png") and f.find("_N") != -1:
            print(os.path.join(root, f))

print(os.path.sep)
```

Here's what I get as an output:

```
c:/data/MA Maps\Map_of_Massachusetts_Nantucket_County.png
c:/data/MA Maps\Map_of_Massachusetts_Norfolk_County.png
\
```

I understand that some of python's library functions *(like open())* will work with mixed path separators (at least on Windows) but relying on that hack really can't be trusted across all libraries.  It just seems like the items returned from **os.walk()** and **os.path** (**.sep** or **.join()**) should yield consistent results based on the *operating system* being used.  Can anyone explain why this inconsistency is happening?

P.S. - I know there is a more consistent library for working with file paths *(and lots of other file manipulation)* called **pathlib** that was introduced in python 3.4 and it does seem to fix all this. If your code is being used in 3.4 or beyond, is it best to use **pathlib** methods to resolve this issue?  But if your code is targeted for systems using python before 3.4, what is the best way to address this issue?

Here's a good basic explanation of **pathlib**: [Python 3 Quick Tip: The easy way to deal with file paths on Windows, Mac and Linux](https://medium.com/@ageitgey/python-3-quick-tip-the-easy-way-to-deal-with-file-paths-on-windows-mac-and-linux-11a072b58d5f)

Here's my code & result using **pathlib**:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

# All of this should work properly for any OS. I'm running Win10.

# You can even mix up the separators used (i.e."c:\data/MA Maps") and pathlib still
# returns the consistent result given below.
base_folder = "c:/data/MA Maps" 

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(base_folder):
    # This changes the root path provided to one using the current operating systems
    # path separator (/ for Win10).
    root_folder = Path(root)
    for f in files:
        if f.endswith(".png") and f.find("_N") != -1:
             # The / operator, when used with a pathlib object, just concatenates the
             # the path segments together using the current operating system path separator.
             print(root_folder / f)


c:\data\MA Maps\Map_of_Massachusetts_Nantucket_County.png
c:\data\MA Maps\Map_of_Massachusetts_Norfolk_County.png
```

This can even be done more succinctly using only **pathlib** and list comprehension (with all path separators correctly handled per OS used):

```
from pathlib import Path

base_folder = "c:/data/MA Maps"
path = Path(base_folder)
files = [item for item in path.iterdir() if item.is_file() and 
                                            str(item).endswith(".png") and 
                                            (str(item).find("_N") != -1)]
for file in files:
    print(file)


c:\data\MA Maps\Map_of_Massachusetts_Nantucket_County.png
c:\data\MA Maps\Map_of_Massachusetts_Norfolk_County.png
```

This is very Pythonic and at least I feel it is quite easy to read and understand.  .iterdir() is really powerful and makes dealing with files and dirs reasonably easy and in a cross-platform way.  What do you think?

Comment: "... that was introduced in python 3.4 and it does seem to fix all this .." – what if the Python maintainers were aware of this issue and that **is** the fix you are looking for?

Comment: But that still leaves os and path inconsistent and at least to my knowledge pathlib is not consistently used.  Most training on Python file handling only discusses using os & path.

Comment: Windows came later, and chose a different path separator `\ ` for copyrights. But it maintained POSIX compatibility, allowing also `/` as path separator. You used a hardcoded start directory with `/`, but the directory walks added subdirectories with a OS standard `\ `. You could normalize, get the absolute path of your hard coded start directory.

Comment: Totally understand the history and why the mixing of / and \ exists.  But don't understand why os and path don't yield consistent results based on the OS being used.  As shown, pathlib deals with all of this under the covers and always provides paths with the correct results independent of OS used.  Seems like os and path should do the same.

Comment: Seems like root (returned from os.walk()) should return the properly separated root folder based on the current OS (regardless of how the base_folder paths are separated).  If it did that, then root and os.path.sep would always be consistent and you would always be assured that your paths are independent of OS.  I would think this type of change to os shouldn't cause issues with existing code (but I might be missing something).

Answer (score 3):

The `os.walk` function always yields the initial part of the `dirpath` unchanged from what you pass in to it. It doesn't try to normalize the separators itself, it just keeps what you've given it. It does use the system-standard separators for the rest of the path, as it combines each subdirectory's name to the root directory with `os.path.join`. You can see the current version of the implementation of the `os.walk` function [in the CPython source repository](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5565c30f0b25996a0e73477fc0e1e1aced52b926/Lib/os.py#L282).

One option for normalizing the separators in your output is to normalize the base path you pass in to `os.walk`, perhaps using `pathlib`. If you normalize the initial path, all the output should use the system path separators automatically, since it will be the normalized path that will be preserved through the recursive walk, rather than the non-standard one. Here's a very basic transformation of your first code block to normalize the `base_folder` using `pathlib`, while preserving all the rest of the code, in its simplicity. Whether it's better than your version using more of `pathlib`'s features is a judgement call that I'll leave up to you.

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

base_folder = Path("c:/data/MA Maps")    # this will be normalized when converted to a string
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(base_folder):
    for f in files:
        if f.endswith(".png") and f.find("_N") != -1:
            print(os.path.join(root, f))
```